# Java modify protobuf value as argument in a method

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

i have a question. I want to modify a value of a protobuf class which i created.
My method looks like this:

```
void modifyFooValue(Baz foo, int value) {
    int newValue = value; 
    Baz.Builder builder = foo.toBuilder();
    builder.getBarBuilder().getFooBuilder().setVal(newValue);
    foo = builder.build();
} ....
```

if i want to modify the value, it still is 5 not 10

```
int val = foo.getVal(); // val == 5
modifyFooValue(foo, 10);
System.out.println(foo.getVal() ); // Should now be 10 but it is 5
```

It is only working if i return a new Baz like this:

```
Baz modifyFooValue(Baz foo, int value) {
    int newValue = value; 
    Baz.Builder builder = foo.toBuilder();
    builder.getBarBuilder().getFooBuilder().setVal(newValue);
    
    return builder.build();
} 

int val = foo.getVal(); // val == 5
foo = modifyFooValue(foo, 10);
System.out.println(foo.getVal() ); // 10
```

But this is not a solution i want. I'd like to change the argument. Is this possible?